# update overwrites emergency.service

Tags: systemd

I changed

> /lib/systemd/system/emergency.service

But after update systemd or another software obviously overwrites it with the original script.

The same situation, if I put the changed script additionally to

> /etc/systemd/system/emergency.service

I tried to connect /lib/systemd/system/emergency.service and /etc/systemd/system/emergency.service with a link and vice versa, both will show the same result, systemd or another packet overwrote it.

Once I change something, I did

> /bin/systemctl daemon-reload

What shall I do to prevent systemd or any other update to overwrite my emergency.service script?

Comment: Can you give the context?

Comment: I want to exchange the single user login (sulogin) with a script.

Comment: It is a Ubuntu 16.04 with console only, no GUI.